# Unable to pip install psycopg2

Tags: django, pip, psycopg2

I have been trying to google this all over the internet and still can't figure out how to get this package installed.  Any help is much appreciated.  I have tried numerous examples from google to no avail.

Mac OS 10.15.3

```
pip freeze
asgiref==3.2.5
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.4
entrypoints==0.3
flake8==3.7.9
gunicorn==20.0.4
mccabe==0.6.1
postgres==3.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
psycopg2-pool==1.1
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pyflakes==2.1.1
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.1
whitenoise==5.0.1


pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.4.tar.gz (377 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/keeganleary/Documents/Coding/life_cal/venv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"
'"'/private/var/folders/s6/f4q9mnjn7q9b34gw7bz35l680000gn/T/pip-install-qwbzap8s/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/va
r/folders/s6/f4q9mnjn7q9b34gw7bz35l680000gn/T/pip-install-qwbzap8s/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open
)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
--egg-base /private/var/folders/s6/f4q9mnjn7q9b34gw7bz35l680000gn/T/pip-install-qwbzap8s/psycopg2/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/s6/f4q9mnjn7q9b34gw7bz35l680000gn/T/pip-install-qwbzap8s/psycopg2/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/Users/keeganleary/Documents/Coding/life_cal/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <mo
dule>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/Users/keeganleary/Documents/Coding/life_cal/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module
>
        from setuptools.depends import Require
      File "/Users/keeganleary/Documents/Coding/life_cal/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 7, in <modu
le>
        from .py33compat import Bytecode
      File "/Users/keeganleary/Documents/Coding/life_cal/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/py33compat.py", line 2, in <m
odule>
        import array
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/array.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2)
: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/array.cpython-38-darwin.so: code signature in
(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/array.cpython-38-darwin.so) not valid for use in proc
ess using Library Validation: Library load disallowed by System Policy
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Hope this helps you